# Delay tick() of each sprite within a globalTick() JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requestanimationframe

There must be a really simple solution for this, as I've tried messing with setInterval(), but can't seem to get the result I want...

I have this globalTick()

```
function globalTick(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,800)

    if(target){
        target.tick();
    }

    // Move arrows
    for(var i = 0; i < spriteList.length; i++){
        spriteList[i].tick()
    }


    window.requestAnimationFrame(globalTick);
}

document.onkeyup = function(e){
    // Change gamestate
    if(e.which == 13){
        $("#state"+gameState).hide()
        gameState ++

        if(gameState == 6){
            // Affect game variables
            player = new Player(0);
            target = new Target(targetX, targetY)

            for(var i = 0; i < player.calculateNotes(); i++){
                timerID = setInterval(spawnArrows(), 3000)
            }
            clearInterval(timerID)
    }

    // ...

spawnArrows = function(){
    // Rabdomize arrows (15 for now)
    var dirCode = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8));
    spriteList.push(new Arrow(dirCode))
    //soundsSequence.push(soundsList[dirCode])
}
```

Then I have this tick() method on my sprites, in this case, an Arrow object

```
    class Arrow{
        constructor(dirCode){
            this.dirCode = dirCode;
            this.speedX = 1
            this.speedY = 1

             switch(this.dirCode){
                // ...
            }

    tick(){
            ctx.fillStyle = "black"
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, spriteSize, spriteSize)

            switch(this.dirCode){
                case 0:
                    this.x += this.speedX
                    break
                case 1:
                    this.x += this.speedX
                    this.y -= this.speedY
                    break
                // ...
```

Ive spared you guys the variable declarations.

What I want is to delay each new Arrow being pushed into the Array by a set time that exists within another object, lets say 3 seconds in the example. Is it even possible to slow down within a globalTick() thats being called 60 times or so a second by requestAnimationFrame? Ideally in pure JS, unless JQuery is the only way to go...

Many thanks, hope that this is clear enough!

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318765/how-can-i-make-3-thousand-requests-to-google-drive-api-using-node-js-without-exc I explained how to make waterfall with promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using a setTimeout queue.

Partially applied `spawnArrow` functions are pushed into the queue. `spawnQueue.shift()();` removes the first function from the queue and calls it.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/800ztcn1)

```js
let notes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
let spriteList = [];
let spawnQueue = [];
let delayTime = 500;

function globalTick() {
    spriteList.forEach(sprite => sprite.tick());
    requestAnimationFrame(globalTick);
}
globalTick();

$('button').click(onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick() {
    let kickOffQueue = spawnQueue.length <= 0;

    notes.forEach(note =>
        spawnQueue.push(() => spawnArrow(note))
    );

    if (kickOffQueue) {
        // here you can set the delay time of the first execution
        consumeSpawnQueue(500);
    }
}

function consumeSpawnQueue(nextDelayTime) {
    if (spawnQueue.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            spawnQueue.shift()();
            consumeSpawnQueue(delayTime);
        }, nextDelayTime);
    }
}

function spawnArrow(note) {
    var dirCode = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8));
    spriteList.push(new Arrow(dirCode, note));
}

class Arrow {
    constructor(dirCode, note) {
        this.dirCode = dirCode;
        this.x = 0;
        this.domEl = $(`<div>${note}${dirCode}</div>`).appendTo('body');
    }

    tick() {
        this.x += 1;
        this.domEl.css({
            marginLeft: this.x
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>spawnArrows</button>
```

Note: setTimeout is not very time accurate - it only gaurentees a minimum delay. If you need time accuracy, you will instead have to calculate elapsed time like this:

```
const startTime = new Date();
const elapsedTime = () => (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
```

In your globalTick game loop:

```
if ((elapsedTime() - lastSpawnArrowTime) > delayTime) {
    spawnQueue.shift()();
}
```

And inside the spawnArrow function, you would set:

```
lastSpawnArrowTime = elapsedTime()
```